# Twig Sprintf Gettext

Tags: php, twig

My question refers to this Twig Extension:

https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/gettext.rst

If i use this for example:

```
<p>{{ _n('One day without accident.', '%d days without accident.', n)|format(n) }}</p>
```

So how can i parse the variables to twig?

I mean %d in this example

It is the first time i need to use Sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` stands for a number. The `format` filter will replace these with the parameters given to that filter. The placeholders (usually `%s` or `%d`) are replaced with the correspondending parameters. So the first placeholder get the value form the first argument and the second from the second argument ect.

For more information, see the php reference: http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: That won't answer my question at all. Please read my question once again. I want to know how to use it in twig.

Comment: I've read it 10 times, but I can't find what I should explain more than I did in this answer. Could you please update your question, so it is more clear?

Comment: I mean how can i parse the variables to twig. I know how to use it directly in php but not in twig. I hope you understand.

Comment: By using the `format` filter. (e.g. `'foo %s'|filter($valueOfThePlaceholder)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in Wouter J's answer (which is the correct answer) it should read

`foo %s'|format($valueOfThePlaceholder)`